# PHP warning files

Tags: 16.04, php, sqlite

I installed php 5.6 in ubuntu 16.04 and I installed package sqlite but now I have this problem

[image]

Comment: How did you install `sqlite`? `.dll` files are specific to Windows.

Comment: Also please don't post screenshots, copy and paste the text into the question and use [formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) instead.

Comment: yes I install sqlite ,in my project i use sqlite not mysql ,therefore I install sqlite

Comment: But *how* did you install it?

Comment: what my friend !!

Answer (score 0):

First remove current php  with this commands

sudo apt-get remove php5 && sudo apt-get autoremove

After try install again with this commands.

sudo apt-get install php5-ldap php5-sqlite php5-mbstring

Comment: Why `php5-ldap`? By the way, there is no package `php5-ldap` for 16.04, buth there is a `php-ldap`.

Comment: Don't use php5.0 ; just php for all dependencies than you get the latest php package for all dependencies